# how can i do a function when radio button is not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i wrote the below code to check if radio button is not checked do another function .but the code does not work here is my snippet :

```js
$('.multiway').change(function(){
   if ($('.multiway').is(':checked')){
       $("#cityadd").removeClass("multiflight");
    $("#cityadd").addClass("multiflight-checked");
   }
   else{
     if ($('.multiway').not(':checked')){
 $("#cityadd").removeClass("multiflight-checked");
    $("#cityadd").addClass("multiflight");
 }}
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .multiflight{display:none !important;}
  .multiflight-checked{display:block !important;}

  </style>  
</head>

<body>
 1 <input type="radio"  class="multiway" name="ways">
    2 <input type="radio"  name="ways">

<div class="newcity multiflight" id="cityadd">HELLOO</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `but the code does not work` ?

Comment: have you tried if (!$('.multiway').is(':checked')) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the event to the `ways` input, instead of to the specific buton:

```
$('input[name="ways"]').change(function(){
   if ($('.multiway').is(':checked')){
       $("#cityadd").removeClass("multiflight");
       $("#cityadd").addClass("multiflight-checked");
   }
   else{
    if ($('.multiway').not(':checked')) {
        $("#cityadd").removeClass("multiflight-checked");
        $("#cityadd").addClass("multiflight");
    }
   }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6xhcfc56/1/

But you can make things more short and elegant, by adding a `value` attribute to the form and question it:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio"  class="multiway" name="ways" value="0">1
<input type="radio"  name="ways" value="1">2
```

JS:

```
$('input[name="ways"]').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val == 0)
    $('#cityadd').removeClass('multiflight')
  else
    $('#cityadd').addClass('multiflight')
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f15LnedL/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.multiway').change(function(){
     if ($(this).prop('checked')){ 
    $("#cityadd").removeClass("multiflight"); 
    $("#cityadd").addClass("multiflight-checked"); } 
else{    
    $("#cityadd").removeClass("multiflight-checked"); 
    $("#cityadd").addClass("multiflight");  
    }
     });
```